# ElasticSearch Node Client on Tomcat - failed to read requesting data

Tags: java, full-text-search, bigdata, elasticsearch

I have exception on tomcat console while using embedded Elastic Search instance. I have configured the embedded instance as a node client cluster, starts off with application runs on tomcat. I've got everything working fine for this cluster, however I'm getting following exception while starting off the instance. I also get same exception when I start another node or shut off existing node for the same cluster.

```
Apr 07, 2015 4:13:28 PM org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ping.multicast
WARNING: [Base] failed to read requesting data from /10.4.1.94:54328
java.io.IOException: Expected handle header, got [15]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.HandlesStreamInput.readString(Hand
lesStreamInput.java:65)
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterName.readFrom(ClusterName.java:64)
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterName.readClusterName(ClusterName.jav
a:58)
        at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ping.multicast.MulticastZenPing$Recei
ver.run(MulticastZenPing.java:402)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Apr 07, 2015 4:13:30 PM org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ping.multicast
WARNING: [Base] failed to read requesting data from /10.4.1.94:54328
java.io.IOException: Expected handle header, got [15]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.HandlesStreamInput.readString(Hand
lesStreamInput.java:65)
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterName.readFrom(ClusterName.java:64)
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterName.readClusterName(ClusterName.jav
a:58)
        at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ping.multicast.MulticastZenPing$Recei
ver.run(MulticastZenPing.java:402)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Apr 07, 2015 4:13:32 PM org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ping.multicast
WARNING: [Base] failed to read requesting data from /10.4.1.94:54328
java.io.IOException: Expected handle header, got [15]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.HandlesStreamInput.readString(Hand
lesStreamInput.java:65)
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterName.readFrom(ClusterName.java:64)
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterName.readClusterName(ClusterName.jav
a:58)
        at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ping.multicast.MulticastZenPing$Recei
ver.run(MulticastZenPing.java:402)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

From the exception it looks like a handshaking problem with other cluster nodes, despite this issue cluster remains healthy and happy to serve payload. I'm using **same ElasticSearch version (1.4.4)** for both java client and external installations. So answer for this question is not valid anymore ([ElasticSearch - failed to read requesting data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21989501/elasticsearch-failed-to-read-requesting-data)). Also note I've checked this with isolated node client (java main program) and I don't get to see this exception there.

Comment: In the logs for Tomcat can you actually see version 1.4.4 as being used?

Comment: @AndreiStefan Thanks for your comment. I've found this is caused by another web application deployed in tomcat not the application i'm interested in. Removing other app solved my problem. Thanks for your answer.